# Sum of Products of all Combinations

Tags: summation, combinations

How to prove that the following expression is true:
$$\sum_{i\neq j}^n x_i x_j = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_j & = \sum_{i=1}^n\left( x_i \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right) \quad (\text{since $x_i$ does not depend on $j$})\\[10pt]
& = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \quad (\text{since the second sum does not depend on $i$}) \\[10pt]
& = \underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2}_{\text{since the two sums are the same.}}
\end{align}

If you now impose the condition that $i\ne j$, excluding the terms in which $i=j$, then the sum of the excluded terms is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2,
$$
so that needs to be subtracted from the first sum found above.

Comment: Nice idea! I am very thankful! i knew that the answer is to be easy.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$(a+b+c+\cdots)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+\cdots)+2(ab+bc+ca+\cdots)$$

Comment: It is true if the summation of LHS is properly understood.

Comment: @EclipseSun, Rectiifed

Comment: I found the answer of my question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329344/what-is-the-square-of-summation