# Square of a summation in probability theory

Tags: probability, summation, expectation

I'm doing an exercise from the book Probability and Random Processes by Grimmett and Stirzaker, and I have difficulty understanding one of the solutions from the solution manual.

I don't understand the expansion of the Expectation that is the last step on page 162. (See image below). I think it may be related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329344/what-is-the-square-of-summation) question, which would explain the first term. $E(I_1^2)$ would equal $E(I_1)$ since $I_1$ is an indicator function. However, I do not understand the other terms.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is coming from expanding the square of a product. Note that
$$\mathbb E \left\{ \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} I_j \right)^2 \right\} = \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} I_j^2 + 2\sum_{j <k} I_j I_k \right]$$
and as you noted, $I_j^2 = I_j$, which gives the first term. For the second, we are summing over all pairs $\{j, k\}$ of distinct numbers in $\{1, \dots, n-1\}$. Let's break this apart into two cases: first, we handle the pairs that are one apart from one another (e.g. $\{1, 2\}, \{4, 5\}$). Here, we get
$$\mathbb E \left[\dots + 2 \sum_{j < k,\ |j-k| = 1} I_j I_k + \dots \right]$$
and there are $(n-1) - 1 = n-2$ such terms, which corresponds to the $2(n-2) \mathbb E(I_1 I_2)$ term. Then, we handle the pairs that are more than one apart from one another by using the independence remarked in the preceding comments:
$$\mathbb E \left[ \dots + 2 \sum_{j < k,\ |j - k| > 1} I_j I_k \right] = \dots + 2\sum_{j < k,\ |j-k| > 1} \mathbb E( I_j) \mathbb E( I_k)$$
Thus, our only task is to count how many terms are in that sum. The set $\{(j, k): 1 \leq j < k \leq n-1\}$ has $\binom{n-1}{2}$ elements, and as previously referenced $n-2$ of those consist of the pairs for which $|j-k| =1$; hence, there are $\binom{n-1}{2} - (n-2)$ terms in the sum. When doubled, that expression is equal to $(n-1)^2 - (n-1) - 2(n-2)$.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. I just wonder, what is the added value of writing $2\binom{n-1}{2}$ as $(n-1)^2 - (n-1)$ instead of $(n-1)(n-2)$? Because that seems to follow more clearly from that step.

Comment: Yeah, I'll confess that I'm not sure why they presented it in that way. Presumably to make the ensuing calculations easier? (I didn't carefully read the parts that followed.) Or maybe they thought about the calculation in some different but equivalent way.