# How to square summation

Tags: statistics, correlation

I am trying to prove that $R^2 $ statistic $=$ `the square of the correlation between X and Y`

For simplicity, I am able to assume that $\bar{x} = \bar{y} = 0$

**What I have so far:**

$R^2 = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_{i} - \bar{y})^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_{i}- \hat{y})^2} {\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \bar{y})^2} $

$(cor(X, Y))^2 = (\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i} - \bar{x})(y_{i} - \bar{y})} {\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \bar{y})^2}})^2 = \frac{?}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i})^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i})^2}$

I am stuck on how to square the numerator to try to prove this case. [I read online](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329344/what-is-the-square-of-summation) that in order to square summations, you must add an additional variable $j$ where $i < j$ in the second summation. However I am confused on how to use that information in this case. I know the proof is probably trivial

Comment: You could just write $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(x_j-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})$.  Is this what you want?  The case where $i<j$ is usually used when you subtract off the squared terms.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for I don't think. I am trying to reach the $R^2$ value above. I am not sure what to do with the j values since they do not appear in the $R^2$ equation